# How to update the current time with more than 2 condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to update my data with the current time but why its still error when simulated in Mysql like this:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GetDate())) AND (jam_pulang <> (Select GetDate()))' at line 1

and below is mine

```
UPDATE Presensi 
SET jam_pulang=(Select GetDate()) 
WHERE NIP IN(SELECT nip from presensi where faceid=101)and Tanggal in(Select Convert(date, GetDate()));
```

Comment: are you sure you are sharing the right query? I can see this part `jam_pulang <> (Select GetDate()))` is not exists in your sql query

Comment: in mysql current date doesnot work ..you can user current_date or current_timestamp or now() function for that

Answer (score 0):

getdate is not a function in mysql.
please edit getdate() to `now()` or `curdate()`

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` is the date function for SQL Server. In MySQL you want to use `NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL GETDATE() Function doesn't work, instead of this you can use **current_date** or **current_timestamp** or **now()::timestamp** function

```
UPDATE Presensi 
SET jam_pulang=current_date
WHERE NIP IN(SELECT nip from presensi where faceid=101)and Tanggal = current_Date;
```